# How to customize Sonatype Nexus running port?

Tags: nexus, sonatype

I am using Sonatype Nexus OSS version 3.2. Can anyone guide me how to customize the port in which Nexus run ?

I am not able to find any config file to customize port and custom the context path?

Currently Nexus is running on `http://<ServerName>:8081/` and I want it to change as `http://<ServerName>:9001/nexus`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to edit `nexus.properties` in `sonatype-work/nexus3/etc/`, specifically the application port. Set this to 9001, restart Nexus Repository and enjoy the ride :)

Comment: thanks  a lot  , i was expecting a config folder for the same under Nexus folder

Comment: After initial installation before the first start there is no etc folder in sonatype-work but you may edit the etc/nexus-default.properties in nexus installation folder.

Comment: Right @DarthHater, I've found this information too in Sonatype Nexus [public documentaion](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/installation/configuring-the-runtime-environment) for Configuring the Runtime Environment.

Comment: don't make the mistake I did: forget to uncomment the application-port, then spend 20 minutes wondering why your changes weren't incorporated into the start.